# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by /wp-includes/formatting.php:5716

Tags: excel, wordpress, header, export-to-excel

I create a custom Export to Excel function to export a report generated in a custom page for a custom post type.

In the function I used the below `headers`:

```
    if(isset($_GET['excelexport'])) {
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.xlsx\";" );
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");        
        exportToExcel();

    }
```

But I keep getting an error message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
> /home/user/public_html/wp-includes/formatting.php:5716) in
> /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/inc/userHistory.php on line 36

I googled for a solution however non has helped.

Comment: Is your code placed in a page template?

Comment: Yes calling a function defined in a file called `func.php` there the `exportToExcel()` is defined to generate a table with certain data queried from Database

Answer (score 0):

That error means that when your code reach that point you already have others header(...) called somewhere else, by Wordpress itself. If u want to get rid of the output until that point and just go with yours you could do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['excelexport'])) {
   

 ob_end_clean(); // Discard all the output generated until this point
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.xlsx\";" );
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");        
        exportToExcel();

    }
```

This should work and remove the error

Comment: Thanks for the info however this didn't resolve the issue, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: If that doesn't work then you can try to execute your code earlier in the WP execution stack and try if that work

Comment: I already tried that before posting the questions. Please not i'm not using any PHP Excel libraries except only headers to be sent exporting Excel file as I found some examples on the internet. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your code will be executed before any output generated by wordpress.

Try this at your functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'my_excel_output');

function my_excel_export() {
    
    if( isset( $_GET['excelexport'] ) ) {
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"report.xlsx\";" );
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");        
        exportToExcel();        
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

After outputting the excel-data you should stop wordpress execution with `wp_die()`

Comment: The solution given have partially helped me however it's exporting the current page as is while the function `exportToExcel()` is defined in a file called `func.php` to generate a custom table with certain data queried from Database